# Renew multiple memberships

Tags: civicontribute, civimember, civixero

I have >400 memberships to renew.

Pressing the Renew hyperlink in **individual** Membership does two things
(1) updates the Membership Expiry if and when payment received
(2) creates a record with a pending invoice in CiviContribute

These invoices get sent automatically to Xero using CiviXero, and when paid in Xero, CiviContribute status gets updated and CiviMember status changes from Pending to Current - very nice !

I want to Renew multiple memberships without having to do the above 400 times.

I can generate a Membership report for the type of membership in question and select the memberships to act on.

In the Action List, I select "Update Multiple Memberships"

I choose the Profile that selects the relevant fields I have identified.

I can update the expiry date for all memberships in a few moments, but this does not trigger the invoice/CiviContribute process.

I have read about an Action "Renew Multiple Memberships" but cannot find this option.

Is it possible to renew multiple memberships including triggering Civi Contribute automatically?

Any help is appreciated.

Joomla V4.  Latest CiviCRM

Answer (score 2):

You could do CiviCRM >> Membership >> Batch entry.

Only thing you need to do is manually select all the contacts.

Comment: That is a very good start and should be able do it that way this year.  Would be great if a list of members found in Find Memberships could be imported into this function so that they could all renewed using Batch Data Entry without the need to manually select all the contacts.  Thanks for the great suggestion.

Comment: We will need some custom coding to allow that via an extension. But it is doable